# Force log messages for CPP files

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

How do I force SVN log messages only for cpp files? Thank you in advance.

This is my current hook script:

```
      #!/bin/sh
      REPOS=”$1"
      TXN=”$2"
      # Make sure that the log message contains some text.
      SVNLOOK=/usr/local/bin/svnlook
      $SVNLOOK log -t “$TXN” “$REPOS” | grep “[A-z a-z]” && exit 0
      echo “Please write a log message describing the purpose of your changes and then     
      try committing again.” 1>&2
      exit 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by [this example](http://wordaligned.org/articles/a-subversion-pre-commit-hook) :

```py
#!/bin/env python
" Example Subversion pre-commit hook. "

def command_output(cmd):
  " Capture a command's standard output. "
  import subprocess
  return subprocess.Popen(
      cmd.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]

def files_changed(look_cmd):
  """ List the files added or updated by this transaction.

"svnlook changed" gives output like:
  U   trunk/file1.cpp
  A   trunk/file2.cpp
  """
  def filename(line):
      return line[4:]
  def added_or_updated(line):
      return line and line[0] in ("A", "U")
  return [
      filename(line)
      for line in command_output(look_cmd % "changed").split("\n")
      if added_or_updated(line)]

def check_cpp_files(look_cmd):
  " Check C++ files in this transaction. "
  def is_cpp_file(fname):
      import os
      return os.path.splitext(fname)[1] in ".cpp .cxx .h".split()
  cpp_files = [
      ff for ff in files_changed(look_cmd)
      if is_cpp_file(ff)]
  return len(cpp_files)

def main():
  usage = """usage: %prog REPOS TXN

Run pre-commit options on a repository transaction."""
  from optparse import OptionParser
  parser = OptionParser(usage=usage)
  parser.add_option("-r", "--revision",
                    help="Test mode. TXN actually refers to a revision.",
                    action="store_true", default=False)
  errors = 0
  try:
      (opts, (repos, txn_or_rvn)) = parser.parse_args()
      look_opt = ("--transaction", "--revision")[opts.revision]
      look_cmd = "svnlook %s %s %s %s" % (
          "%s", repos, look_opt, txn_or_rvn)
      if check_cpp_files_for_tabs(look_cmd) > 0:
          # check the length of the commit message :D
          # if not correct, print the error on sys.stderr.write("Please write a log message describing the purpose of your changes and then     
  try committing again.")
  except:
      parser.print_help()
      errors += 1
  return errors

if __name__ == "__main__":
  import sys
  sys.exit(main())
```